# While finding eulidean distance, I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
while finding Euclidean Distance of my chromosomes. Here is my code:

```
organisms=[canis_lupus,Drosophila_melanogaster,Felis_catus,Homo_sapiens,Mus_musculus]

def euclidean_distance(p,q):
   distance = np.linalg.norm(p-q)
   return distance

edistance = []
for i in range(len(organisms)):
  for j in range(i+1,len(organisms)):
     edistance.append(euclidean_distance(organisms[i],organisms[j]))

print(edistance)
```

Please note that if I print organisms, each element is basically a list of length 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p-q` is interpreted as a list subtraction (since `p` and `q` are lists), which is not defined. Convert your lists to np.arrays first:

```
distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(p)-np.array(q))
```